# Using Kaniko inside Kubernetes - Error: error resolving dockerfile path

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kaniko

I'm getting the same error message as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55351690/5437918). However after trying all the suggestions on that post, I'm still unable to resolve my issue, which is described in the following.

I'm using [Kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) to build and push images for later use. I've ensured the image pushing portion of the job works by building a test Dockerfile and `--context` from a publicly-accessible git repo.

So now I'm trying to build images by using a mounted hostPath directory `/root/app/containerization-engine/docker-service` as the build context, which you can see indeed exists, along with its `Dockerfile`, in the following shell output:

```
[root@ip-172-31-60-18 kaniko-jobs]# ll -d /root/app/containerization-engine/docker-service/
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root root 4096 May 24 17:52 /root/app/containerization-engine/docker-service/
[root@ip-172-31-60-18 kaniko-jobs]#
[root@ip-172-31-60-18 kaniko-jobs]#
[root@ip-172-31-60-18 kaniko-jobs]#
[root@ip-172-31-60-18 kaniko-jobs]# ll -F /root/app/containerization-engine/docker-service/
total 52
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root   104 May  9 01:50 app/
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 20376 May 25 12:02 batch_metrics.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  7647 May 25 12:02 batch_predict.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root    14 May 25 12:02 dev_requirements.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   432 May 25 12:02 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   136 May 25 12:02 gunicorn_config.py
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    19 May  9 01:50 hooks/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    37 May  9 01:50 jenkins/
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   158 May 25 12:02 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    37 May  9 01:50 models/
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     0 May 25 12:02 README.md
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   247 May 25 12:02 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    94 May  9 01:50 utils/
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   195 May 25 12:02 wsgi.py
```

The job manifest `containerization-test.yaml` that I'm running with `kubectl apply -f` is defined below:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: kaniko-containerization-test
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kaniko
        image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest
        args: ["--dockerfile=Dockerfile",
               "--context=dir:///docker-service",
               "--destination=jethrocao/containerization-test:v0",
               "--verbosity=trace"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: docker-service-build-context
          mountPath: "/docker-service"
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kaniko-secret
          mountPath: "/kaniko/.docker"
          readOnly: true
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
      - name: docker-service-build-context
        hostPath:
          path: "/root/app/containerization-engine/docker-service"
          type: Directory
      - name: kaniko-secret
        secret:
          secretName: regcred-ca5e
          items:
          - key: .dockerconfigjson
            path: config.json
          optional: false
```

The job is created successfully, but the pods that are created to run the job keep on erroring out, and inspecting the log from one of these failed attempts, I see:

```
[root@ip-172-31-60-18 kaniko-jobs]# kubectl logs kaniko-containerization-test-rp8lh | head
DEBU[0000] Getting source context from dir:///docker-service
DEBU[0000] Build context located at /docker-service
Error: error resolving dockerfile path: please provide a valid path to a Dockerfile within the build context with --dockerfile
Usage:
  executor [flags]
  executor [command]

Available Commands:
  completion  Generate the autocompletion script for the specified shell
  help        Help about any command
```

To triple confirm that the hostPath directory and the `Dockerfile` it contains are both accessible when mounted as a volume into a container, I changed the batch job into a deployment object (running a different image not Kaniko), applied that, `kubectl exec -it` into the running pod, and inspected the mounted path `/docker-service`, which exists, along with the full contents of the directory. I then wrote to the `Dockerfile` within just to test write accessibility, and it worked as expected; and the written change persisted outside of the container in the cluster's node too.

I'm really at a loss at what could be the problem, any ideas?

Comment: Well, while doing that `exec`, did you run kaniko with those args to reproduce the bad outcome manually? Have you tried including `/docker-service/Dockerfile` to see if that makes it happier?

Comment: @mdaniel I did try passing in the absolute path `/docker-service/Dockerfile` to `--dockerfile`, with the exact same results. I'll give running Kaniko manually a shot from within the container now, and report back.

Comment: The error turned out to be a careless mistake on my part: I used 2 `volumeMounts` blocks in the `containers` block, when it should be a single one with 2 elements within it.